# iOS BLE peripheral writeValue doesn't work if I readValue

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a peripheral in a MacOS app and a central on iOS. The central has the following code:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
        print(characteristic.uuid)
        switch characteristic.uuid {
        case bleCharacteristics().read:
            print("Read it!")
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
            peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
            break
        case bleCharacteristics().write:
            print("Write to it!")
            peripheral.writeValue("Heyooo".data(using: .utf8)!, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
            break
        case bleCharacteristics().notify:
            print("Subscribe to it!")
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
            break
        default:
            print("Got to the characteristics default somehow")
        }
    }
}
```

The readValue works fine, but writeValue doesn't work at all (as in the peripheralManager's didReceiveWriteRequests never gets called). If I comment out the readValue then the writeValue works just fine. No where in the docs does it say that readValue is a blocking async operation or anything like that so I have no idea what's going on.

If anyone has any ideas what I'm doing wrong I'd be much obliged.

Comment: I suppose I should also say that I've tried putting writeValue well after readValue has completed, and it still doesn't work. It seams that once I readValue to one characteristic I can no longer writeValue to another characteristic.

Answer (score 1):

Well sometimes you've gotta post the question to figure out the answer. In my peripheral code I had:

```
func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveRead request: CBATTRequest) {
    let response = "Hey there".data(using: .utf8)
    request.value = response
    peripheral.updateValue(response!, for: characteristics![0] as! CBMutableCharacteristic, onSubscribedCentrals: [request.central])
}
```

Which was "reading" the value due to the updateValue method, but wasn't closing the read request. Adding the line:

```
peripheral.respond(to: request, withResult: .success)
```

is the proper way to respond to the read request and made it so that writeValue worked as expected. Correct peripheral code:

```
func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveRead request: CBATTRequest) {
    let response = "Hey there".data(using: .utf8)
    request.value = response
    peripheral.respond(to: request, withResult: .success)
}
```